# How to deploy python applications to remote machines running Windows

Tags: python, windows, deployment

I develop a distributed application which is based on RabbitMQ and multiple python applications. System is pretty complex so it is very likely that we will need to update deployed solution multiple times. Customer wants that we use his servers which are running windows. So the question is how to deploy and update python part of this system. And as sub-question is it better to deploy sources or use pyinstaller to get executables and then deploy them? On my test server I just use git pull when I have some changes which is probably not the case for production system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was in a similar position and i combine pyinstaller with fabric. So i build a "compile" version of the project and with fabric, i deploy like the client wants.

Fabric support roles definition, several configuration for several clients.

Comment: But as I know fabric uses SSH which is probably tricky to master on Windows platform. Do you install OpenSSH to handle this?

Comment: Thank you, will try it myself